# How do I create a cudaTextureObject_t from linear memory?

Tags: c++, cuda, textures

I cannot get bindless textures referencing linear memory to work -- the result is always a zero/black read. My initialization code:

The buffer:

```
int const num = 4 * 16;
int const size = num * sizeof(float);
cudaMalloc(buffer, size);

auto b = new float[num];
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    b[i] = i % 4 == 0 ? 1 : 1;
}
cudaMemcpy(*buffer, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

The texture object:

```
cudaTextureDesc td;
memset(&td, 0, sizeof(td));

td.normalizedCoords = 0;
td.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
td.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
td.addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
td.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;
td.sRGB = 0;

td.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
td.maxAnisotropy = 16;

td.mipmapFilterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
td.minMipmapLevelClamp = 0;
td.maxMipmapLevelClamp = 0;
td.mipmapLevelBias = 0;

struct cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));
resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeLinear;
resDesc.res.linear.devPtr = *buffer;
resDesc.res.linear.sizeInBytes = size;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.f = cudaChannelFormatKindFloat;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.x = 32;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.y = 32;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.z = 32;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.w = 32;

checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateTextureObject(texture, &resDesc, &td, nullptr));
```

The kernel:

```
__global__ void
    d_render(uchar4 *d_output, uint imageW, uint imageH, float* buffer, cudaTextureObject_t texture)
{
    uint x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    uint y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if ((x < imageW) && (y < imageH))
    {
        // write output color
        uint i = y * imageW + x;
        //auto f = make_float4(buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);
        auto f = tex1D<float4>(texture, 0);
        d_output[i] = to_uchar4(f * 255);
    }
}
```

The texture object is initialized with something sensible (4099) when given to the kernel. The Buffer version works flawlessly.

Why does the texture object return zero/black?

Comment: As you allocate single floats and not float4s, I guess your array is not properly aligned.

Comment: Well, the cuda runtime api says: malloc(): "The allocated memory is suitably aligned for any kind of variable."

Comment: Also, I tried accessing the memory as single floats before I posted.

Comment: You should use `tex1Dfetch` to read the texture object within the kernel, and you must be running on a Kepler GPU for it to work. Without looking at the code too closely I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [CUDA programming reference guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-functions) You need to use `tex1Dfetch()` to read from one-dimensional textures bound to linear texture memory, and `tex1D` to read from one-dimensional textures bound to CUDA arrays. This applies to both CUDA texture references and CUDA textures passed by object.

The difference between the two APIs is the coordinate argument. Textures bound to linear memory can only be addressed in texture coordinates (hence the integer coordinate argument in `text1Dfetch()`), whereas arrays support both texture and normalised coordinates (thus the float coordinate argument in `tex1D`).